Is it possible to modify the comma separated assignments to space separated assignments?
the item in \definevar command is separated by comma, is it possible to use spaces instead ?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\pp}{O{2} m}{\fpeval{round(#2, #1)}}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definevar}{m}
 {% #1 = comma separated assignments <var>=<value>
  % <var> should be undefined
  \xcn_var_def:n {#1}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\setvar}{m}
 {% #1 = comma separated assignments <var>=<value>
  % <var> should be defined
  \xcn_var_set:n {#1}
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \fp_new_variable:n { V }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \fp_set_variable:nn { V }

\seq_new:N \g__xcn_var_list_seq

\keys_define:nn { xcn/var/def }
 {
  unknown .code:n =
   \fp_new_variable:V \l_keys_key_str
   \seq_gput_right:NV \g__xcn_var_list_seq \l_keys_key_str
   \fp_set_variable:Vn \l_keys_key_str {#1},
 }
\keys_define:nn { xcn/var/set }
 {
  unknown .code:n =
   \seq_if_in:NVTF \g__xcn_var_list_seq \l_keys_key_str
    {
     \fp_set_variable:Vn \l_keys_key_str {#1}
    }
    {
     \msg_error:nnV { xcn/var } { illegal-var } \l_keys_key_str
    }
 }

\msg_new:nnnn { xcn/var } { illegal-var }
 {
  Illegal~variable~'#1'~in~\token_to_str:N \setvar
 }
 {
  The~variable~'#1'~hasn't~been~defined~with~\token_to_str:N \defvar
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \xcn_var_def:n { \keys_set:nn { xcn/var/def } {#1} }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \xcn_var_set:n { \keys_set:nn { xcn/var/set } {#1} }

\NewDocumentCommand{\usefpvar}{m}{ \fp_eval:n {#1} }
\NewCommandCopy{\?}{\usefpvar}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\definevar{b=0.24,
           h=5.1,
           A=b*(b+h),
           I=b*(b+h)^3/12
          }

$A=\?{b}\times(\?{h}+\?{b})=\?{A}$ m$^2$

$I=\?{b}\times(\?{h}+\?{b})^3/12=\pp[4]{\?{I}}$ m$^4$


\end{document}



I have said you repeatedly that you can use \direcltua inside LuaTeX. The commands processed in Lua are separated only by spaces. I.e.:
\directlua{
  b = 0.24
  h = 5.1
  A = b * (b+h)
  I = b * (b+h)^3/12
}

You don't need any special macros in this case.
If you insist on using macros for reading such obscure syntax, then following code does it. I suppose that you have a macro \setvar{variable}{value} created already and that it is not subject of your question here. So, I defined such macro only by \wterm in order we can see on terminal that scanning of given syntax works.
\def\afterfi#1#2\fi{\fi#1}

\def\addcomma #1{\addcommaA #1 }
\def\addcommaA #1 #2 {\ifx ,#2,,#1\romannumeral`\^^@\else \space #1\afterfi{\addcommaA #2 }\fi}

\def\definevar #1{\defvarA#1\end}
\def\defvarA #1#2\end{\expandafter\defvarC\expanded{\defvarB {}=x #1#2==},={},}
\def\defvarB #1=#2={\ifx;#2;#1\else \addcomma{#1 }=\afterfi{\defvarB#2=}\fi}
\def\defvarC #1=#2,{\defvarD}
\def\defvarD #1=#2#3,{\ifx;#1;\else\setvar{#1}{#2#3}\expandafter\defvarD\fi}

\def\setvar#1#2{\wterm{variable "#1" is set to "#2".}}

\definevar{
  b = 0.24
  h = 5.1
  A = b * (b+h)
  I = b * (b+h)^3/12
}

\bye

The macro works in two steps. First, it adds commas before the last spaced-separated item between each =, it means that ...= 2 * 3 X =... replaces by ...= 2 * 3,X=.... It is done by \defvarB and \addcomma macros. Second step reads comma separated list with equal sign inside them. The macro is expandable.

How does one type Chinese in OpTex ?

I don't think this is a good interface as I personally would use spaces inside of equations to make them more legible. However, this is indeed possible, though you'll need to change your parsing a bit to use something that splits on spaces instead of directly using the keyval parser.
Also (just like I did before) I changed your implementation to use the low level \keyval_parse:nnn instead of \keys_set:nn with an unknown .code:n, I think this is the more semantically correct approach (and it has better performance) and allows us to throw a meaningful error message on input missing a value (though l3fp wouldn't complain about an empty assignment I guess it's not that useful and doubt you want that behaviour, and even if you wanted it you could still use it explicitly by saying a={} or similar).
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\pp}{O{2} m}{\fpeval{round(#2, #1)}}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definevar}{m}
 {% #1 = space separated assignments <var>=<value>
  % <var> should be undefined
  \xcn_var_def:n {#1}
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\setvar}{m}
 {% #1 = space separated assignments <var>=<value>
  % <var> should be defined
  \xcn_var_set:n {#1}
 }

\seq_new:N \g__xcn_var_list_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \xcn_var_set:n { \__xcn_var_assign:Nn \__xcn_var_check:n }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \xcn_var_def:n { \__xcn_var_assign:Nn \__xcn_var_new:n }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__xcn_var_assign:Nn #1#2
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { ~ } {#2}
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
      {
        \keyval_parse:nnn
          { \msg_error:nnn { xcn/var } { missing-value } }
          { \__xcn_var_assign_aux:Nnn #1 }
          {##1}
      }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__xcn_var_assign_aux:Nnn #1#2#3
  {
    #1 {#2}
    \fp_set_variable:nn {#2} {#3}
    \prg_break_point:
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__xcn_var_new:n #1
  {
    \fp_new_variable:n {#1}
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g__xcn_var_list_seq {#1}
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__xcn_var_check:n #1
  {
    \seq_if_in:NnF \g__xcn_var_list_seq {#1}
      {
        \msg_error:nnn { xcn/var } { illegal-var } {#1}
        \prg_break:
      }
  }

\msg_new:nnnn { xcn/var } { illegal-var }
  { Illegal~variable~'#1'~in~\token_to_str:N \setvar }
  { The~variable~'#1'~hasn't~been~defined~with~\token_to_str:N \defvar }

\msg_new:nnnn { xcn/var } { missing-value }
  { Missing~value~for~variable~'#1' }
  { Every~variable~needs~to~be~assigned~a~value }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\usefpvar}{m}{ \fp_eval:n {#1} }
\NewCommandCopy{\?}{\usefpvar}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\definevar{b=0.24
           h=5.1
           A=b*(b+h)
           I=b*(b+h)^3/12
          }

$A=\?{b}\times(\?{h}+\?{b})=\?{A}$ m$^2$

$I=\?{b}\times(\?{h}+\?{b})^3/12=\pp[4]{\?{I}}$ m$^4$


\end{document}


Of course, something like b= 0.24 would give some problems…

@egreg exactly hence first sentence :P

If you want to use weird syntax, you're on your own. Suppose you pass your carefully crafted code to a friend who likes to leave spaces around = symbols (maybe also around *) and tries
\definevar{
  b = 0.24
  h = 5.1
  A = b * (b+h)
  I = b * (b+h)^3/12
}

After all, your friend knows that spaces are ignored in math formulas (and also in expl3 fp-expressions). The main effect is that you lose a friend.
Slightly better might be to split at newlines, but then, what's the advantage?
\documentclass{article}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\pp}{O{2} m}{\fpeval{round(#2, #1)}}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definevar}{+v}
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { \obeyedline } {#1}
  \xcn_var_def:e {\seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {,}}
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \fp_new_variable:n { V }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \fp_set_variable:nn { V }

\seq_new:N \g__xcn_var_list_seq

\keys_define:nn { xcn/var/def }
 {
  unknown .code:n =
   \fp_new_variable:V \l_keys_key_str
   \seq_gput_right:NV \g__xcn_var_list_seq \l_keys_key_str
   \fp_set_variable:Vn \l_keys_key_str {#1},
 }
\keys_define:nn { xcn/var/set }
 {
  unknown .code:n =
   \seq_if_in:NVTF \g__xcn_var_list_seq \l_keys_key_str
    {
     \fp_set_variable:Vn \l_keys_key_str {#1}
    }
    {
     \msg_error:nnV { xcn/var } { illegal-var } \l_keys_key_str
    }
 }

\msg_new:nnnn { xcn/var } { illegal-var }
 {
  Illegal~variable~'#1'~in~\token_to_str:N \setvar
 }
 {
  The~variable~'#1'~hasn't~been~defined~with~\token_to_str:N \defvar
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \xcn_var_def:n { \keys_set:nn { xcn/var/def } {#1} }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \xcn_var_def:n {e}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \xcn_var_set:n { \keys_set:nn { xcn/var/set } {#1} }

\NewDocumentCommand{\usefpvar}{m}{ \fp_eval:n {#1} }
\NewCommandCopy{\?}{\usefpvar}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\definevar{
  b = 0.24
  h = 5.1
  A = b * (b+h)
  I = b * (b+h)^3/12
}

$A=\?{b}\times(\?{h}+\?{b})=\?{A}$ m$^2$

$I=\?{b}\times(\?{h}+\?{b})^3/12=\pp[4]{\?{I}}$ m$^4$


\end{document}


